# How to set color code in excel using conditional formatting- based on year?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Morning Everyone,

how to set color code on excel sheet based on **year.**

example :

i. red - expired

ii. Yellow - three months before expired

iii. Orange - a month before expired.

below is the example on how i want it to be on excel sheet.

[image]

i have tried some formula using conditional formatting - only red color are being marked but not yellow and orange.

kindly need your help. thank you so much.

Comment: Have you done ANY research? A quick google search will point you in the right direction.

Comment: i did.  the only formatting that success was red color .and mostly what i found is based on month/ a year but not more than a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates you provided do not act as a good example since they are years apart, not months apart. You can do this with a conditional formatting equation. Simply subtract the two dates (Expiration Date - Current Date).

If A1 = Expiration Date and A2 = Current Date, go to "Conditional Formatting>Manage Rules>New Rule>Use Formula To Determine Which Cells to Format, and then set the following three rules:

```
=A2-A1 < 1, Set formatting Red
=A2-A1 < 31, Set formatting Yellow
=A2-A1 < 91, Set formatting Orange
```

Once you have added these conditional formats, go back to "Manage Rules" and then make sure the rules are in this exact order.

Comment: After re-reading your post I am a little confused. You emphasize you want this done based on YEAR, but your formatting conditions are based on MONTHS and your excel dates dont make sense. The one that is shown as expired appears to be a year away from expiration. I'm not sure if this is what you need - please let me know and I will attempt to update if not!

Comment: oh sorry my bad, i didn't check before upload the picture. ok, for example, medical start 24-5-2018, expired 27-5-2020.. so, in 3 months before the expired which is 27-2-2020 it will turn yellow and a month 27-4-2020 will turn orange. then on the actual date, it turns red. sorry if my explanation earlier confused you. image above is based on our HR explanation.

Comment: Then the solution I provided will do what you need it to do although I would change your header columns to be more clear. Just change the cell references to match your set up